# How do I submit response to list via form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, power-automate

I have been looking for information how to submit data to a list via a form? I looking for guidance how to do this.

Previous I had it on SP2013:

1. Create a list with required fields
2. Create an approval WF
3. Modify form that will show items information and add writable fields for User2
4. After User2 submit data. Information would be updated via WF itself into the list
5. User1 would get a response with filled information

How could I achieve that on SharePoint Online Cloud version?

I am thinking of doing this way:

1. Create a list.
2. Use Microsoft Forms to create a submit form.
3. Update fields using Power Automate.

I am currently learning and looking for information on SPOnline Cloud. Any useful tips and guides would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can still do it the same way. Or using the sharepoint designer, that would work too with SHarePoint online sites.

MS forms would not work as its more like a survey and not be feasible to update list items.

Or the whole flow can be automated via Power Auotmate but then you would have to think about the licensing part because there can be limited number of instances that can be executed as per the licensing you purchased.

Comment: Hello, licensing part isn't an issue. If I understood you correctly I would just need to connect my Designer to SPOnline site and edit that way?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

We could use PowerApps Canvas App to submit form to SharePoint Online list.

Refer to following articles for more information:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-sharepoint-online-customize-list-form-with-powerapps-canvas-app/

https://www.sharepointsky.com/powerapps-submit-form-to-sharepoint-list/

Comment: Are you talking about new form? If yes I know how to do that. I need to have an option to modify a display form and couple buttons there